# Jira API returned Gitlab issue link -> extract more data about the Gitlab issue

Tags: api, gitlab, jira

When using the Jira API to return issues from a project, there is a JSON field called "customfield_12900" that contains a Gitlab issue link. I presume this is because we have Jira integration with Gitlab. However, the link is not in a valid format to use the Gitlab API to extract data from it.

An example of a URL can be "https://gitlab.gildeskagerak.com/ram/ram-platform/main/-/issues/65

My question is: how can I take the given Gitlab URL and extract data about the given issue? In this case, with ID 65.

Comment: @Eisenknurr I could create a proper URL if I had the project id as well, something I do not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query the Gitlab API with the repository name and go from there

```
curl "https://gitlab.foo.bar/api/v4/projects/?private_token=xxxxx&search=ram-platform"
```

and you should get something like

```
[
   {
      "path_with_namespace" : "ram/ram-platform",
      "web_url" : "https://gitlab.foo.bar/ram/ram-platform",
      "path" : "ram-platform",
      "service_desk_address" : null,
      "operations_access_level" : "enabled",
      "issues_enabled" : true,
      "readme_url" : null,
      "shared_with_groups" : [],
      "namespace" : {
         "id" : 433,
         "kind" : "group",
         "name" : "ram-platform",
         "full_path" : "ram-platform",
         "avatar_url" : null,
         "web_url" : "https://gitlab.foo.bar/groups/ram-platform",
         "parent_id" : null,
         "path" : "ram-platform"
      },
...
]
```

Get your ID from there.